# Inject $http into Tour of Heroes Component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I have the Tour of Heroes app running, but I want to extend it to make ajax calls.

I have a WebAPI service that serves up the data (CORS enabled) and have proven it w/ a silly little non Angular client using JQuery $.post and $GetJson ... All was going well...

Here is my hero-details.component.ts file 
(happy to include any others that may help...)

```
import {Component , Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'hero-detail',
    templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
    styleUrls : ['./hero-detail.component.css']
})

export class HeroDetailComponent {  // implements OnInit  {
    @Input() hero: Hero;

    powers = ['Really Smart', 'Super Flexible', 'Weather Changer'];
    submitted = false;

constructor(
    private heroService: HeroService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location,
    $http     //**--LINE OF INTEREST #2**
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']))
}
save(): void {
    this.heroService.update(this.hero)
        .then(() => this.goBack());
}


goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
}

onSubmit() { this.submitted = true; }

callService( ) {    

    var uri = 'http://localhost:61212/api/heros';

   //**// LINE OF INTEREST #1**
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: uri
    }).then(function () { alert('success'); }, function () { alert('fail');});
};
```

}

If I try to compile I get

```
TS2304: Cannot find '$http'
```

I can comment the $HTTP call (Line of Interest #1 ) and it compiles, it runs and i do  enter the function and hit a breakpoint where i declare and assign the variable "uri".  So I am reasonably sure I have the problem isolated.

So I believe, based on hours of googling, that I need to DI the $http object into this component

But when I pass $http into the constructor (LINE OF INTEREST #2) I get the following error when I try to compile

```
TS7006 Parameter '$http' implicitly has an 'any' type
```

I have googled this so much Larry and Sergy have asked me to knock it off. 
What I have found is $http being passed into controllers, maybe Im missing something, but I can not seem to translate those articles into something that works for this.

**1) Am I right that injecting the $http object is what needs to be done**

**2) What is the syntax?**

Comment: Which version of angular 2 are you working on ? Why `$http` and not just `private http: Http` ?

Comment: @angular/common@~4.0.0
my answer to your question is simply because I am trying to use google as a learning tool, its awesome, but sometimes sends you down a rabbit hole... All the pages I have pulled up seem to have $http passed into the constructor. Let me try dropping the $

Comment: it turns out the example I was using was Angular 1 code. I did not realize that until I tried some other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when I was googling , i was just googling angular and most the articles were for angular1.  Thats why I was seeing answers that involved controllers, etc.

angular2 is much different. If you are trying to get off the ground, try searching angular2 instead. at least the articles you run across will be relevant.

if you are using visual studio.. here is a nice link to get you started...

https://jonhilton.net/2016/12/01/fast-track-your-angular-2-and-net-core-web-app-development/